# Translate greek characters in PostgreSQL full-text search

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, tokenize, postgresql-14

I would like to translate greek characters to their common latin equivalents for the purpose of full-text search.

Consider the following:

```
SELECT
    to_tsvector('english', 'α-decay') @@ to_tsquery('α & decay') AS greek_greek,
    to_tsvector('english', 'α-decay') @@ to_tsquery('a & decay') AS greek_latin_short,
    to_tsvector('english', 'α-decay') @@ to_tsquery('alpha & decay') AS greek_latin_long;

 greek_greek | greek_latin_short | greek_latin_long
-------------+-------------------+------------------
 t           | t                 | f
(1 row)
```

The long version does not match, but users expecting these symbols might type in *alpha* or *beta* instead of α and β. Is there a pre-defined dictionary which would automatically turn α into both 'a' and 'alpha'? If not, how can I make one? Or is there a better way altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use a [synonym dictionary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SYNONYM-DICTIONARY) with a synonym file like:

```
α alpha
β beta
ɣ gamma
...
```